# CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5.2

I recently migrated an application from asp.net mvc2 to asp.net mvc5. In the past while deploying the asp.net mvc2 application to web server, I never deployed web.config files for the Areas, Views. Hence in case of asp.net mvc5 application also, I have not deployed the web.config files for the Areas, Views.
But after deployment, when I started testing I got the following error:

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model' does not exist in the current context
Can anyone help me to know to whether it is required to include the web.config files for the Areas, Views as part of the package that needs to be deployed to the server.

Comment: Sounds like a reference to a variable `model` just hasn't been instantiated. IIRC, mvc2 might have been a little more friendly about undeclared types a la JavaScript http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8zbaa6f.aspx

Comment: On including the web.config files for the Areas, Views as part of the package fixed the issue but I want to know whether it is required to include  it as part of the package in case of asp.net mvc5